# Can I enable TRIM for SD card as if it was a SSD?

Tags: sd-card, trim

I have two old laptops that run Ubuntu / Arch (I am not an expert linux user, just learning), and they have:

1) 1.8 inches hard drive with a (flat thin) ZIF connector.

2) 2.5 inches IDE hard drive.

I am considering replacing their hard drives mainly because they have small capacity, and possibly on the way I would gain some speed.

There are options like IDE-to-SDCard and ZIF-to-SDCard and ZIF-to-mSATA adapters.

I was about to buy the SD card options (ridiculously cheap) but I am afraid TRIM could not be enabled on them in case the interface of these adapters hides (just wondering, I do not know) that they are a really SD card, so the OS would wear too quick they read/write cycles if treated as a mechanical hard hard drive.

Can I enable TRIM on just any drive?

Any advice that I should avoid SD cards for this purpose?

These two laptops are my hobby machines where I experiment things I do not want to try on my main machines, not really willing to spend too much on them.

Comment: You can't enable trim on a device that does not support it. SD cards do not support trim.

Comment: Should I then avoid the SD options and go for the mSATA ones, right?

Answer (score 0):

SD cards support fstrim and blkdiscard when plugged in as emmc device.